# Symfony2 tree builder - what does the method canBeUnset() do?

Tags: configuration, symfony

```
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('form')
            ->info('form configuration')
            ->canBeUnset()
            ->treatNullLike(array('enabled' => true))
            ->treatTrueLike(array('enabled' => true))
            ->children()
                ->booleanNode('enabled')->defaultTrue()->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
```

Line 5 of the above snippet from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration` uses the method `canBeUnset()`.  I don't know what this does because it seems to not do anything if I remove it.  I'm working understanding semantic configuration for my own bundles.

Answer (score 6):

Following the code, you can find definition for this method in `Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/ArrayNodeDefinition` class.

```php
/**
 * Sets whether the node can be unset.
 *
 * @param Boolean $allow
 *
 * @return ArrayNodeDefinition
 */
public function canBeUnset($allow = true)
{
    $this->merge()->allowUnset($allow);

    return $this;
}
```

This is passed to MergeBuilder ( `Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/MergeBuilder` ) which handles config merging.

```php
/**
 * Sets whether the node can be unset.
 *
 * @param Boolean $allow
 *
 * @return MergeBuilder
 */
public function allowUnset($allow = true)
{
    $this->allowFalse = $allow;

    return $this;
}
```

So my understanding is, that this method defines, if your config value can be unset while merging configurations, in case the overriding config does not support the value. I would have to test though, to find out the behaviour if the unsetting is not allowed, but I guess then it would throw an exception about a missing config value just like `isRequired`.

Comment: But how do you unset a configuration value? For instance `framework.profiler` is set in `config_dev.yml` and `config_test.yml` includes `config_dev.yml`. The profiler is only disabled if there's no such configuration key `framework.profiler`. So how can I unset it? Setting it to `{}` or `~` didn't work. (Symfony 2.1, I know that this can be done as of 2.2 with `framework.profiler.enabled`).

Comment: To actually unset the value use `form: false` (`{}` and `~` won't unset it).